# want to display string containing date from json response to required format

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Titanium
I have a json response which contains 

`{
"start_time :"2015-06-24T14:00:00.000Z"
}`

I am trying in the following format **June 24, 2015 14:00**

For now I am trying following code but I am not getting any success

```
Alloy.Globals.getFormattedTime = function(time) {
var amPM = '';
var d = new Date(time);

var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
month = month + '';
if (month.length == 1) {
    month = '0' + month;
}

var day = d.getDate();
day = day + '';
if (day.length == 1) {
    day = '0' + day;
}

var year = d.getFullYear();
year = year + '';

var currentHour = d.getHours();

if (currentHour < 12) {
    amPM = 'AM';
} else {
    amPM = 'PM';
}

if (currentHour == 0) {
    currentHour = 12;
}

if (currentHour > 12) {
    currentHour = currentHour - 12;
}

currentHour = currentHour + '';
if (currentHour.length == 1) {
    currentHour = '0' + currentHour;
}

var currentMinute = d.getMinutes();
currentMinute = currentMinute + '';

if (currentMinute.length == 1) {
    currentMinute = '0' + currentMinute;
}

var currentSeconds = d.getSeconds();
currentSeconds = currentSeconds + '';

if (currentSeconds.length == 1) {
    currentSeconds = '0' + currentSeconds;
}

return month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + currentHour + ':' + currentMinute + ':' + currentSeconds + " " + amPM;};
```

Can anyone help on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output you're getting now?

Answer (score 4):

If indeed what I understand is correct and you need the date formatted like this: 'June 24, 2015 14:00', try this script:

```
function formatDate(d) {
  var dd = d.getDate(),
      yy = d.getFullYear(),
      monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      mm = monthNames[d.getMonth()],
      hh = d.getHours(),
      min = d.getMinutes();


  if ( dd < 10 )  dd = '0' + dd;
  if ( hh < 10 )  hh = '0' + hh;
  if ( min < 10 )  min = '0' + min;

  return mm +' '+ dd +', '+ yy + ' ' + hh + ':' + min;  
}
```

Check [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jw40yjn4/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Roumelis George 
I tried your code.
It is working .
Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help Bunny. Since it is working can you accept it and maybe upvote it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try moment.js, which is a library for handling the dates, its a wrapper created around date object, you can find the complete documentation on this [link](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Back to your question, using moment js you would need to do just this much, you can pass the parameter which you got from your json object to the moment.

```
    var moment = require (alloy/moment);
    var date = new moment("2015-06-24T14:00:00.000Z");
    date = date.format("MMMM DD, YYYY HH: MM");
```

Hope this helps you and reduce the number of code lines.